# How can I use XCopyArea with colors other than blue in Xlib?

Tags: c++, graphics, x11, xlib

I'm trying to build a ray tracer in C++. To that end, I'd like to draw the final image to a window (instead of just outputting to PPM, which is what I'm currently doing). I have some code below that saves the color of each pixel to an array that matches the size of an image and then attempts to display that image using Xlib. This code snippet below allocates data to a 100 x 100 array image:

```
int width = 100;
int height = 100;

int data[width * height * 4];

for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++){

  data[i] = 255;

}
XImage *image  = XCreateImage(d, DefaultVisual(d, 0), 24, ZPixmap, 0, (char*) data, 100, 100, 32, 0); 

Pixmap pm = XCreatePixmap(d, w, 100, 100, 24);

XPutImage(d, pm, gc, image, 0,0,0,0, 100, 100);
```

This outputs a nice blue square in my window. But, if I change the `for` loop in the above example to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i+= 4){

  data[i] = 255;
  data[i + 1] = 255;
  data[i + 2] = 0;  
  data[i + 3] = 0;

}
```

I still get blue with some black mixed in, but I expected yellow. What am I doing wrong here?

Full code below for reference:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  Display *d;
  Window w;
  XEvent e;
  const char *msg = "Hello, World!";
  int s;

  d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  if (d == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  s = DefaultScreen(d);
  w = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, RootWindow(d, s), 10, 10, 500, 500, 1,
                          BlackPixel(d, s), WhitePixel(d, s));
  
  GC gc = XCreateGC(d, w, 0, NULL);

  XSelectInput(d, w, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);
  XMapWindow(d, w);

  int width = 100;
  int height = 100;

  int data[width * height * 4];

  for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++){

    data[i] = 255;

  }

  XImage *image  = XCreateImage(d, DefaultVisual(d, 0), 24, ZPixmap, 0, (char*) data, 100, 100, 32, 0); 

  Pixmap pm = XCreatePixmap(d, w, 100, 100, 24);

  XPutImage(d, pm, gc, image, 0,0,0,0, 100, 100);

  while (1) {
    XNextEvent(d, &e);
    if (e.type == Expose) {
        XCopyArea(d, pm, w, gc, 0, 0, width, height, 10, 10);
    }
    if (e.type == KeyPress)
        break;
  }

  XCloseDisplay(d);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. If I remember where I found the original sources for some of this stuff, I'll link it in an edit. But basically below is a working `for` loop. I'm not entirely sure why I need it, but after every RGB triplet, we need a byte of `0x00`. This is on my computer where I have 24-bit true color depth (which is probably the same as every modern computer). So if you have 24 bits, then you have 3 bytes on every line which, for many reasons that I don't know, is illegal. If someone could explain this to me, I'd really love to know. The code is below:

```
unsigned char data[width * height * 4];

  for (int i = 0; i < width * height * 4; i+=4){

    data[i] = 255; // blue channel
    data[i + 1] = 0; // green channel
    data[i + 2] = 255; // red channel
    data[i + 3] = 0; // dead pixel that is always zero

  }
```

Comment: Many modern graphics cards/systems use the 32-bit-per-pixel scheme (it makes things align as integers better and generally improves performance). In *some* of those systems, your 4th (dead) byte is the alpha channel, giving RGBA format.

Comment: @AdrianMole I was thinking that the 4th might be alpha. I'm coming from a Python programming background where there are no types. To my understanding, alpha would be a double between 0.0 and 1.0. If that's the case, I wouldn't be able to assign a true alpha in this array, which has a type of unsigned short. How does alpha work in this case?

Comment: The alpha channel - like the R, G and B, components, is a value 0..255. Exactly how it is used varies between systems but it is often a measure of transparency. The translation between the 0...255 and 0..1 ranges is trivial, though.

Comment: I can't speak authoritatively for other systems but, in Windows bitmaps, data are often used as 32-bit values but the 4th byte is simply ignored. Raw, 24-bit data exist but each 'row' needs to be 4-byte aligned, so storing data as 24-bit data requires all sort of weird padding.